# Natural combination between Python and TeX

Tags: python, plot, tex

As a graduate, I often plot various kind of figures and have found many plotting software.

I appreciate the high quality drawings in TeX, using tools like Asymptote and Tikz. As a poor programmer, I also need the flexibility brought by Python when I need do some complex calculations during plotting. The combination from both side, which I deeply believe, will be a perfect choice.

So, is there any chance for me to find some software like this, with both **Simple** and **Beatiful** in mind.

Comment: [IPython's notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) can typeset LaTeX using MathJax and you can include images...

Answer (score 1):

There are several python libraries which excel at various types of graphics such as [MayaVi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/).

Here is an example of simple TeX integration with matplotlib in python (not showing all the math stuff, but just the plotting code:

```
figure(2)
plot(x,Ni[:,1], 'b.', x, y, 'r.', x, z, 'g.', markersize=10)
xlabel('nm')
ylabel('Sulfur normalized intensity')
legend(['Ni/S', r'exp profile $\tau$ = 200 nm', r'exp profile $\tau$ = 98 nm'], loc='best', numpoints=1)
pylab.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15, left=0.15)
show()
```

which produces:

[image: Notice the use of embedded TeX]

Notice the tau is actually just a snippet of TeX embedded into the image.  Most of the matplotlib commands allow this so you can draw equations into your image or whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I'm seeking for is something gorgeous like [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), and [this](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/), both of which rely heavily on `TeX` processing. The only problem is the way to do programming, which I deadly prefer the Python way like `Matplotlib` but desire much **pretty** plotting. `PyX` is close in this sense, but its [3D graphs](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/examples/3dgraphs/index.html) sucks.

Comment: Well, for 3D, MayaVI is the cats meow.  If you are looking to draw shaded regions in your plots and the like, you may also want to take a peek at Veus (http://home.gna.org/veusz/)?